# Windows is connected via WI-FI and no DHCP hast no connection to router for the first 2 minutes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

A windows machine I work with shows quite an odd behaviour:

I connect via WI-FI to a router and has DHCP disabled providing my machine with a static local IP.
Now windows boots up and says, that I have a connection but no internet.

If I ping the router -> no route to it, all packets are dropped.
The fun part is: When I do nothing for hours, the internet connection remains broken.

When I open firefox and keep accessing a resource like google.com etc for about two minutes, the connection somehow get its gears together and starts working.
Instead of firefox I can use Acrylic Wifi Free.
The odd thing: Acrylic Wifi Free sometimes shows that I am working on two channels (I don't have them at hand, but like 1+5), after I get a proper internet connection I am usually only on one channel, e.g 1.

I've flushed DNS (albeit pinging router's IP should not be affected by this)
I've updated the wifi driver (it's a PCI device from TP-Link).
Coincidently I even moved. The new area has only one other network and since the router is on auto there should be no channel collisions. Due to the moving I got a new router, same crappy model but new hardware, same effect.
There should be no other machine in the network with the same IP.
Other machines in the network have no issues connecting to the network.

While writing about this I realized that this initial two channel display on Acrylic may indicate something. My router has one antenna, how-ever my PCI card has two. Is it possible that initially the WI-FI driver uses different channels for TX/RX and later realizes that one of them is silent? I've actually never heard of that and I am unaware if this is configurable on windows.

Edit: More hints: The router is a simple one, no 5GHz range. So is the PCI card: TP-Link TL-WN851ND

Edit2: Clarification on those questions: DHCP is enabled on the router. The static route is set on the machine.
My settings are `192.168.1.44/255.255.255.0`, Gateway and DNS is `192.168.1.1`

When I have an established connection but no internet, ipconfig shows that I have the proper router IP 192.168.1.1 set up.

I am not near that machine atm, I remember that when DHCP was turned on, I first got an entirely different IP for the SSID, like 224.x.x.x. The SSID is however quite unique and not a standard network. Even if somebody would broadcast the same SSID, I doubt that I would have the right password for that ...
But again just in case: Even if my gateway was 192.168.1.1 and I assumed I have a valid IP I was not able to ping the router until I get internet back.

Comment: You have DHCP disabled on the router, or you are setting a static IP for your computer?  When you first connect and can't ping the router, what ip address do you have.  Run an "ipconfig" from a command prompt and post results.  Mainly looking for "IP Address, Subnet mask, and gateway" for your TP-Link Wireless Card.

Comment: @N.Greene I made an edit to clarify the things you asked (almost)

Comment: Can you configure the router to always issue the same IP-address (by DHCP) to your PC ? (A DHCP reservation.) That should fix your issues because then the router 'knows" the PC right from the moment it gives out the DHCP address.  As it is now it takes the router a while to realise that there is client out there that it doesn't know about, but it should supply routing for. (A good router can deal with this properly, but the ones supplied by ISP's are usually the cheapest junk they can buy... With the usual consequences for quality...)

Comment: Continued... Another trick that works in some cases: If the router can't do DHCP reservations sometimes it is able to do port-forwarding. Just setup a dummy forward to an arbitrary port on the PC. Enabling UPNP in the router (if it has the feature) may also help to speed things up.

Comment: @Tonny I switched to vanilla DHCP without doing something on the router and I get a valid IP after a reboot for my local network as any other device does but I am unable to ping the router via ICMP, o_0. I checked Acrylic again, I am on 3+7 when connected and not working and after spamming F5 on firefox I drop down to channel 3 only, with working internet. Side info: I got a blue screen after changing to DHCP, on Win10. Can't remember last time when that happened. Will analyze the dump later, maybe the KMODE_EXCEPTION points to a network driver

Comment: @Samuel I strongly suspect a flaky Wifi driver. Combined with that BSOD it's almost certain. Is that Wifi driver native for W10 (Microsoft supplied) or did it come from the vendor, in the latter case is it a real W10 driver or a Win7 or Win8 driver that is also supposed to work under W10? I have seen several laptops using a Win7 driver under W10 that were very unstable. Reverting to the Microsoft default Wifi drivers can make it stable, although sometime you loose the dual-channel capability of the Wifi adapter with the Microsoft no-nonsense drivers.